# Python - How to detect and decode multiple Datamatrix from an image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, qr-code, barcode, datamatrix

I have been trying to detect *barcodes*, *QR codes* and *Datamatrix* from a label.
The **pyzbar** library detects barcodes and QR codes but fails to detect datamatrix.
Then I tried  **pylibdmtx** library which decodes only one datamatrix from an image (which has 6 datamatrix codes). It is also very slow! :(

Is there any other way to detect multiple datamatrix from an image?

Here is my code for datamatrix :

```
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import decode
import cv2
import numpy as np


def dataMat(image, bgr):
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    data = decode(gray_img)
    print(data)
    for decodedObject in data:
        points = decodedObject.rect

        pts = np.array(points, np.int32)
        pts = pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
        cv2.polylines(image, [pts], True, (0, 255, 0), 3)

        cv2.putText(frame, decodedObject.data.decode("utf-8") , (30, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,
                    bgr, 2)

        print("Barcode: {} ".format(decodedObject.data.decode("utf-8")))

bgr = (8, 70, 208)

frame  = cv2.imread('datamat.png')
code = dataMat(frame, bgr)
print(code)
cv2.imshow('Data Matrix reader', frame)
code = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried supplying a good high res image?

Comment: @ZdaR Yes, I did! I tried with many samples, but it is detecting only one datamatrix in each sample

Comment: In the documentation examples it is detecting multiple objects, Can you try with the test image provided with the repo? `pylibdmtx/tests/datamatrix.png`

Comment: Yes, I tried with the sample image and it works. But I am trying with real images, and it's not working the same there! My codes are denser than the sample image.@ZdaR

Comment: Then maybe you need to pre-process the input images to make them more crisp. Try Binary thresholding the image and then passing it over to the library.

Comment: Give a try to Aspose.BarCode Cloud SDK for Python, it can read multiple barcodes from an image. https://products.aspose.cloud/barcode/python

Comment: There is also a blog post here explaining how some pretreatments can be applied to improve further code detection https://kdmurray.id.au/post/2022-03-21_decode-qrcodes/